# Django saml2 login missing session variables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, saml

For my Django application, I am trying to enable SSO using Djangosaml2 and following are the versions I am using

djangosaml2==1.2.0

pysaml2==7.0.0

djangorestframework==3.12.2

Django==3.1.7

python==3.8

My saml2_settings is as follows

```
from os import path
import saml2
import saml2.saml

from app.local_settings import SERVER_URL


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'djangosaml2.backends.Saml2Backend',
)

SAML_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'saml_session'

SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING = {
    'username': ('username', ),
    'email': ('email', ),
    'first_name': ('first_name', ),
    'last_name': ('last_name', ),
}

BASEDIR = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
LOGIN_URL = '/saml2/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/saml2/logout/'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SAML_CREATE_UNKNOWN_USER = True
SAML_SERVER_URL = '10.23.1.114'

SAML_ENABLED = True

# MIDDLEWARE.append('djangosaml2.middleware.SamlSessionMiddleware')


SAML_CONFIG = {
  # full path to the xmlsec1 binary programm
  'xmlsec_binary': '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',

  # your entity id, usually your subdomain plus the url to the metadata view
  'entityid': path.join(SAML_SERVER_URL, 'saml2/metadata'),

  # directory with attribute mapping
  'attribute_map_dir': path.join(BASEDIR, 'attribute_maps'),

  # this block states what services we provide
  'service': {
      # we are just a lonely SP
      'sp' : {
          'name': 'Dummy app',
          'allow_unsolicited': True,
          'authn_requests_signed': True,
          'force_authn': True,
          'want_response_signed': True,
          'want_assertions_signed': True,
          'logout_requests_signed': True,
          'name_id_format_allow_create': False,
          'endpoints': {
              # url and binding to the assetion consumer service view
              # do not change the binding or service name
              'assertion_consumer_service': [
                  (path.join(SAML_SERVER_URL, 'saml2/acs/'),
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
              ],
              # url and binding to the single logout service view
              # do not change the binding or service name
              'single_logout_service': [
                  (path.join(SAML_SERVER_URL, 'saml2/ls/'),
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                  (path.join(SAML_SERVER_URL, 'saml2/ls/post/'),
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
              ],
          },
      },
  },
  # where the remote metadata is stored, local, remote or mdq server.
  # One metadatastore or many ...
  'metadata': {
      'local': [path.join(BASEDIR, 'idp_metadata.xml')]
      },

  # Signing
  'key_file': path.join(BASEDIR, 'samlkey.key'),  # private part
  'cert_file': path.join(BASEDIR, 'samlcert.pem'),  # public part

  # own metadata settings
  'contact_person': [
      {'given_name': '--',
       'company': '--',
       'email_address': '--',
       'contact_type': '--'}
      ],
  # you can set multilanguage information here
  'organization': {
      'name': [('--', 'en')],
      'display_name': [('--', 'en')],
      'url': [('--', 'en')],
      },
  "valid_for": 24
  }
```

My middleware is as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'app.middleware.APPMiddleware',
    'djangosaml2.middleware.SamlSessionMiddleware'
]
```

With the above mentioned settings I am facing a couple of issues

1. After successfully authenticating from my SSO server by the time the request reaches my /login Url both the request.session and request.saml_session variables are getting reset and I am getting a complete new session ID. And also I am missing the saml_session attributes due to this issue. I did add a debug point in the djangosaml2 views and in there just before returning the response I could see the attributes present. But for some reason by the time the request reaches my app, its getting reset.
2. When I try to logout on saml2/logout, I am seeing the following error:

```
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name_qualifier'
```

I cant seem to find what I am missing here. I have tried all I could think of but stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following two things, then it started working for me

1. Downgraded the djangosaml2 and pysaml version to 0.19.0 and 4.9.0 respectively.
2. For HTTPS connection, added SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True and for dev i.e. run server cases, SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False in your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating Django from 1.1 to 3.1. Your codebase actually fixed my issue. I added the `SESSION_SERIALIZER` in my `saml/config.py`:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

And added `SamlSessionMiddleware` in `settings.py`:

```
djangosaml2.middleware.SamlSessionMiddleware
```

My issue was:

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'saml session'

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this an answer to the original question? Or are you saying the answer to the original question managed to solve a different issue you were encountering?